# Basic inequalities with norms in vector spaces with topology

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $Y$ be a closed vector subspace of a normed space $(X, \| \cdot \|)$ such that $X \neq Y.$ I need to know why this is true: Let $u \in X \backslash Y,$

1. If $c = \inf_{v \in Y} \| u - v \|,$ then $c > 0.$
2. For all $d > c,$ there is some $w \in X$ such that $c \leq \| u - w \| \leq d.$

A fellow student said the first one was true because "$Y$ is closed," but I don't see why this imples $c > 0.$ The second item I think it has something to do with open balls, but i'm not really sure.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose by contradiction that $c=0$, then by definition of infimum  there exist a sequence $y_n \to u$  with, $y_n \in Y \,\,\,\forall n$, but since $Y$ is closed, we would have that
$u\in Y$, contradicting our assumption $u\notin Y$. For the second item use the definition of infimum again, since $c=inf_{v\in Y}\|u-v\|$, then given an $\epsilon>0$ there exists a 
$v\in Y$ such that $c\leq\|u-v\|\leq  c+\epsilon$. So take $\epsilon =d-c>0$ since, $d>c$ and the result follows.